# Get vertex buffer bound to vertex array

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm writing an OpenGL application, and the problem I'm facing now is as follows:

Let us say I have a Vertex Array, with its ID. However, I do not have its bound vertex buffer ID at hand. I am in need of the Buffer ID for an operation. SO, is it possible to retrieve current buffer binding from vertex array?

Note that I have come across `glGetIntegerv`, however I think it only retrieves current buffer binding, NOT vertex array binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let us say I have a Vertex Array, with its ID. However, I do not have its bound vertex buffer ID at hand.

In a well-behaved application, that should not be possible. It was your application that put that buffer into that VAO. Therefore, you should already know what buffer is attached to it. It's a question you don't need to ask.

However, if you have no other choice but to ask OpenGL a question that you ought to know the answer to, you must first bind the VAO to the context. If you're not using the [separate attribute format API](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Separate_Attribute_Format), then you can use `glGetVertexAttribiv` with `GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`, specifying the attribute index you're interested in querying. If you want to use the separate attribute format API, you need to use `glGetIntegeri_v` with `GL_VERTEX_BINDING_BUFFER`, specifying the binding index to query.

If you're using [DSA](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access) (which *requires* using the separate attribute format), then you can use `glGetVertexArrayIndexediv`, with `GL_VERTEX_BINDING_BUFFER` and the appropriate binding index.

Comment: What you have given is absolutely the right answer. However, I've decided to redesign - and now the pipeline(vertex array abstraction) has ID of vertex and index buffers.